Bash: ! inside or outside of square brackets
Is there any meaningful/behavioural difference between putting a ! inside or outside of square bracket tests?
e.g. Is there a difference between:
# if file exists but is empty, exit
[[ ! -s "${file}" ]] && exit 1

and
# if file exists but is empty, exit
! [[ -s "${file}" ]] && exit 1

I'm asking generally, not specific to the -s test. For example, does any of this change when working with numbers, or with multiple tests?

The difference is when you have more than 1 element inside. ! [[ A || B ]] is equivalent to [[ ! A && ! B ]] (boolean algebra).

In the first case, ! is an operator specific the [[ .... ]] command and negates the next expression.  In the second case, ! is an "operator" (don't know the official term for it), which inverts the exit code of any arbitrary command, and is used here in particular to invert the exit code of the whole [[ ... ]] command.

It negates everything inside the brackets if you place it outside the brackets. It's an if not (negates the adjacent term) only if you place it inside the brackets. Consider multiple terms with && (and ||) like
! [[ -s "/usr/bin/env" || "1" == "0" ]] && echo true

is logically different from
[[ -s "/usr/bin/env" || ! "1" == "0" ]] && echo true

